# Spring: configure two datasources (jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName)

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Here my `pom.xml` related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.1.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```

I've coded two configuration objects:

```
@Configuration
public class MssqlBatchConfigurationStep {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     *
     * @param dataSource
     */
    public MssqlBatchConfigurationStep(@JobDataSource DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

As you can see, `dataSource` constructor parameter is qualified with `@JobDataSource`:

The other configuration object is:

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfiguration {

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @JobDataSource
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.job-datasource")
    public DataSource jobDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

And, my `application.proerties` is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/spring-boot-h2-db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.job-datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ac_txt_p
spring.job-datasource.username=sa
spring.job-datasource.password=StR0nGp4ss.
spring.job-datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.job-datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

When I start spring-boot I'm getting this message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at net.gencat.clt.arxius.connector.ConnectorApplication.main(ConnectorApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1000) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.isEnabled(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:79) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.initialize(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:59) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:55) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

My custom qualifier is:

package net.gencat.clt.arxius.connector.config.qualifiers;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface JobDataSource {

}
```

Comment: Try `spring.job-datasource.jdbc-url`, see [Configure a Custom DataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-a-datasource) (search for _"However, there is a catch."_)